# How MongoDB works for this case?

Tags: mongodb, performance, database-design, architecture, nosql

I have a doubt about MongoDB, I know 'what is mongo' but I am not sure if this database is good for a requirement that I need to do. Well, here I go.

**Description:**
I need to store some data from devices (200 devices more o less) and those devices will report every 30 seconds geolocalization data (lat, long), so it will be 576.000 objects/day (2880 request = 1 device per day)

I thought this structure for my documents inside of 'locations' collection

```
{
"mac": "dc:a6:32:d4:b6:dc",
"company_id": 5,
"locations": [
    {
        "date": "2021-02-23 10:00:02",
        "value": "-32.955465, -60.661143"
    }
]
}
```

where 'locations' is an array that will store all locations every 30 seconds.

**Questions:**

1. Is able MongoDB database to do this?
2. Is correctly my document structure to solve this?
3. When this array will be a very big month after, What will happen?
4. There is a better way to do this? (database, framework, etc)

TIA !!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. Is able MongoDB database to do this?

   Yes, this will be fine.
2. Is correctly my document structure to solve this?

   No, not at all!

   **Never** store date/time values as sting, it's a design flaw. Use always proper `Date` object. (This applies for any database).

   Similar statement applies for the coordinate, don't store it as string. I recommend a [GeoJSON Objects](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/geojson/), then you can also create index on it and run spatial queries. Example: `location: { type: "Point", coordinates: [ -32.955465, -60.661143 ] }`
3. When this array will be a very big month after, What will happen?

   The document size in MongoDB cannot exceed 16MiByte, it's a fixed limit. So, it does not look like a good design. Maybe store locations per day or even one document per report.
4. There is a better way to do this? (database, framework, etc)

   Well, ask 5 people and you will get 6 answers. At least your approach is not wrong.

Comment: `Well, ask 5 people and you will get 6 answers. At least your approach is not wrong`. That is so TRUE.

Comment: Thanks! I will think about this!

Comment: @JuanAndres is a good practice to vote up for an useful answer.

Comment: @HanielBaez yeah I know but I haven't reputation yet yo do it.

Answer (score 0):

1. **Is able MongoDB database to do this?** Yes
2. **Is correctly my document structure to solve this?** No
3. **When this array will be a very big month after, What will happen?** The maximum BSON document size is 16 megabytes.
4. **Is there a better way to do this?
   (database, framework, etc)** Yes. [The Bucket Pattern](https://www.mongodb.com/blog/post/building-with-patterns-the-bucket-pattern) is a great solution for when needing to manage Internet of Things (IoT) applications.

You can have one document per device per hour, and a location document where the keys are the lapse each 30 seconds.

```
{
    "mac": "dc:a6:32:d4:b6:dc",
    "company_id": 5,
    "date": ISODate("2021-02-23T10"),
    "locations": {
        "0": "-32.955465, -60.661143",
        "1": "-33.514655, -60.664143",
        "2": "-33.122435, -59.675685"
    }
}
```

Adjust this solution considering your workload and main queries of your system.

Comment: Hi Haniel, thanks very much for your answer, I going to read more about "the bucket pattern".  but I kept thinking about this "You can have one document per device per hour, and a location document where the keys are the lapse each 30 seconds.". Sound good that solution but:

1- Is a  good practice create a document per hour? Doing of this way. I will get 4800 documents per day (assuming that I have 200 devices) 

2- What happend after one year? (1752000 documents)  

3- According to my little experience with MongoDB and NoSQL I ask you: Are normal database sizes for MongoDB?

Comment: I have a MongoDB with 3 billion documents (which gives 50 million buckets) per day - so don't worry about your "cute" database.